# call of overloaded 'min(int&, int&)' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, templates

I got some problem on template.This code passed under vc6 but failed under g++.
Is there anybody could tell me the reason? thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
T min(T x, T y) {
    return (x < y ? x : y);
}

int main() {
    int i1 = 23, i2 = 15, i;
    float f1 = 23.04, f2 = 43.2, f;
    double d1 = 0.421342, d2 = 1.24342343, d;
    i = min(i1, i2);
    f = min(f1, f2);
    d = min(d1, d2);
    cout << "The smaller of " << i1 << " and " << i2 << " is " << i << endl;
    cout << "The smaller of " << f1 << " and " << f2 << " is " << f << endl;
    cout << "The smaller of " << d1 << " and " << d2 << " is " << d << endl;
}
```

> "/usr/bin/make" -f
>   nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE=
>   SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
>   "/usr/bin/make"  -f
>   nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk
>   dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/traincpp mkdir
>   -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX rm -f build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/newmain.o.d g++
>   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/newmain.o.d -o
>   build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/newmain.o
>   newmain.cpp newmain.cpp: In function
>   'int main()': newmain.cpp:13: error:
>   call of overloaded 'min(int&, int&)'
>   is ambiguous newmain.cpp:5: note:
>   candidates are: T min(T, T) [with T =
>   int]
>   /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:182:
>   note:                 const _Tp&
>   std::min(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with
>   _Tp = int] newmain.cpp:14: error: call of overloaded 'min(float&, float&)' is
>   ambiguous newmain.cpp:5: note:
>   candidates are: T min(T, T) [with T =
>   float]
>   /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:182:
>   note:                 const _Tp&
>   std::min(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with
>   _Tp = float] newmain.cpp:15: error: call of overloaded 'min(double&,
>   double&)' is ambiguous newmain.cpp:5:
>   note: candidates are: T min(T, T)
>   [with T = double]
>   /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:182:
>   note:                 const _Tp&
>   std::min(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) [with
>   _Tp = double] make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/newmain.o]
>   Error 1 make[1]:**  [.build-conf]
>   Error 2 make: ** [.build-impl] Error
>   2
>
> 生成 失败 (退出值 2， 总计时间： 623毫秒)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's because you've imported all of the [`std` namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c), which is a [no-no](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.5). Note the other candidates are template `std::min`. Remove the `using namespace std;` and either import select symbols:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

or qualify them:

```
std::cout << "The smaller of " << i1 << " and " << i2 << " is " << i << std::endl;
```

Comment: +1 - [why using namespace std is considered bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Comment: Sorry for my foolish mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you already have a definition for min() in g++.

Comment: Not probably but definitely. `min` is a standard C++ template function in `std` namespace, which got imported.

Comment: Was probably cause must be a beginner who did not know it!

Comment: bingo! I am a beginner in cpp

Comment: @Shisoft, Well good to know that you accept it and are willing to learn. Good luck with C++ !!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `iostream` include appears to also be bringing in the standard `min` call as well and the compiler can't figure out if you want the standard one (because of your `using namespace`) or your own. Just remove your own `min` and use the standard library's version.

Comment: The include brings in `std::min` which is fine. The problem is the `using namespace std`

Comment: This is a practice of college course,I have solved this problem by change the name.

Answer (score 1):

instead of writing std::cout, u may use the namespace std, and create your function min in another namespace, say abc... so now when u call your function min, just write abc::min.. this should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

The function **swap()** is already exists in `iostream`. Therefore, it conflicts with your *swap()* function. You may have to specify that which swap() you want to use or change the name of your swap function like *swap1(), swap2()* etc. You could change any letter into UPPERCASE of your swap function like ***Swap()*** this could resolve the problem without removing `using namespace std;`

otherwise, just remove `using namespace std'` and type

```
using std :: cout;
using std :: endl;
```

instead OR write the code like -

```
std :: cout << "After swapping - a = " << a << ", b = " << b << std :: endl;
```

That's it. Thank you.